# how to create a mobile layout without showing the report (only in mobile)

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I create a report page with the custom visual that pit and looking good only for mobile layout and not for a regular report. 
my question is how can I hide the report from user is the service and the user can view the report only in the mobile app.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The user either has rights to see the report, or doesn't. How he looks it is another question. In your case you can embed the report somewhere (e.g. in a page in web app), with it's [mobile layout](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile), and give the user access to this embedded report (web page) only, without giving him access to the underlying Power BI report at all.